# Duplicate strings in ArrayList of object

Tags: android, string, arraylist, duplicates

I have looked around few examples and cant get my head around it.

I have an List of object and there are some duplicate IDs(strings) in some of those object. What i am trying to do is to go through that list, pick IDs and remove object with duplicate ID and only keep one of them I am feeling rather dump at the moment.

Comment: Thought of trying a HashMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
List<String> list;
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(list));
```